# C# Windows Services using WinSCP assembly mismatch as object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, service, winscp

I am writing a code to upload a file to an sftp server via WinSCP.
Everything else in my code works except when i started to include WinSCP into the code. The Assembly setup fails as it shows error where Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is running on Windows Services using VS 2010 included with WinSCP .net references.

Below is the code that sets up the assembly , i am not able to use NuGet as that requires higher version of Visual Studio.

So i have to create this assembly which i got from WinSCP web itself however i do not understand what i am missing here.

```
            try
            {
                Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                string resName = executingAssembly.GetName().Name + "." + "WinSCP.exe";
                using (Stream resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
                using (Stream file = new FileStream(executablePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    resource.CopyTo(file);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Cant setup assembly : " + ex.Message);
```

Result should be that when the assembly successfully created , then the upload sessions will be able to go through as at the moment the upload sessions i am receiving an error "The version of C:\Windows\TEMP\WinSCP.tmp311D.exe () does not match version of this assembly somedir\WinSCPnet.DLL (5.15.2.0)."

A small assistance will be very helpful.

Comment: Why can't you just use newer version of VS? Community edition is free*

Comment: @vasily.sib i am using 2010 pro btw.

Comment: So what? Why can't you just use newer version of VS?

Comment: Sorry i might not be aware on the differences , i'll check on pro vs community edition. However , can you help on what am i missing at the moment?

Comment: no, because you code is about saving `<yourAssemblyName>.WinSCP.exe` from resource file to some `executablePath`. There is nothing about **loading** an assembly.

Comment: First, you say that you get *"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"*, but later you claim to get *"The version of  ..."* - So what error do you get? + We need [mcve].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl , only the Object Reference not set to an instance of an object is my problem. its due to that i have the Version error as it fails to create the assembly.

Comment: Still waiting for [mcve].

Comment: i found the problem. apparently i already have the assembly , that is why the error mentioned that i have the wrong assembly version. But , the main reason it couldnt match is because 1 ) the temp WinSCP is created in a folder where my program does not have access to. 2 ) i copy pasted the WinSCP exe instead of Adding via "Add Item" in VS. 3 ) i then hard code the executablepath to the WinSCP.exe to fix assembly looking into the wrong folder.... my problem has been solved. thank you everyone.

Comment: If you believe your situation can happen to others, post your solution as an answer. Otherwise delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, I already have the assembly, that is why the error mentioned that I have the wrong assembly version. But, the main reason it couldn't match is because

1. The temp WinSCP is created in a folder where my program does not have access to.
2. I copy-pasted the WinSCP exe instead of Adding via "Add Item" in VS.
3. I then hard code the executable path to the WinSCP.exe to fix assembly looking into the wrong folder.

My problem has been solved.